# GTK - Python Pixbuf From List

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk, gtk3, gdkpixbuf

I got icon data into a Python list. How could I get this icon data into pixbuf? I could not find it in [this](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/GdkPixbuf-2.0/classes/Pixbuf.html) source.

Here is the code I get icon data:

```
from gi.repository import Gio

apps = Gio.AppInfo.get_all()
icon = apps[0].get_icon()
print(icon)
```

Python 3, GTK3, OS: Debian-like Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find how to get `Gio.AppInfo` icons into pixbuf, but I solved my problem in another way.

I have found Desktop application files in the `/usr/share/applications/` location. I could get specific application icon by reading `.desktop` file of it. Fİnally I could get the icon into pixbuf by using `new_from_file()` command.

Answer (score 0):

The code that works in my machine is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from gi.repository import Gio

apps = Gio.AppInfo.get_all()
icon = apps[0].get_icon().to_string()
print (icon)
```

The following also works:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from gi.repository import Gio

apps = Gio.AppInfo.get_all()
icon = apps[0].get_icon()
print (Gio.ThemedIcon.get_names(icon))
```